# Implement onTimer function over ProcessWindowFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

Is there a way to implement the `onTimer()` method over a `ProcessWindowFunction` instead of a `KeyedProcessFunction` or there is any other way to do this?

I have this structure and cannot change it:

```
stream.window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.minutes(gapTime))).allowedLateness(Time.minutes(5000))
       .process(new MyProcessFunction());
/*The idea is to use the onTimer method or a similiar method if exist inside MyProcessFunction*/
public class MyProcessFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction<IN, OUT, KEY, W>{}
```

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

A `ProcessWindowFunction` doesn't have access to timers. Its only role is to process a window's contents whenever the window's Trigger returns FIRE.

Triggers can have timers. So one possible solution might be to use a custom Trigger that causes the `ProcessWindowFunction` to have additional, time-based, firings.

Another solution in cases where the window API isn't flexible enough is to implement your own custom windowing using a `KeyedProcessFunction`.